# H2. How to format a number

Tags: sql, format, h2

i have the following numbers "12.6" and ".78"

i want to format them, something like this.

"12,60 €" and "0,78 €"

How can i do this with h2 and sql?

thx.

Comment: I don't know `H2`, `Replace` function with `string concatenation` will get you the job done.

Comment: yes it does, but it replace only dots, but i need a little bit more. i need something like this {0:#.##}

Answer (score 3):

TO_CHAR(.78,'999D00') => 0,78

[format description](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0300__Conversion-Functions/FormatParameters.htm)

Comment: did you find the solution,is this?

Answer (score 0):

if this is decimal variable on Model in ASP.NET - you should to change DisplayFormat:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.##} €", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```